# Prevent user from selecting a value less than a scale before

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, conditional-statements

I have a scale (radio buttons) in a form that allows the user to select a value from 0 to 10.

I have a second scale (radio buttons) below it, which also allows the user to select a value from 0 to 10.

Using jQuery ideally.. how would I go about preventing the user from selecting a value in the second scale that is less than the value in the first scale?

The markup looks something like below (although this is stripped back for the sake of the example)

```
<div class="scale_a">

    <div class="frm_scale">
        <label for="field_a">
        <input type="radio" id="field_a_1" value="0">0</label>
    </div>

    <div class="frm_scale">
        <label for="field_a">
        <input type="radio" id="field_a_2" value="1">1</label>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to create a loop for this work
Its not done just an aprox example

```
$(".scale_a input").forEach(function(ele){
    if(ele.val() < [your previous obj val] ){
    ele.attr("disabled",true)
    }
})
```

Comment: I like where you're going with this Ritesh.. I'll have a play with it and see what I come up with.

Answer (score 0):

On select of first radio get the value and and disable all other radio in second radio less than the selected value.